# what is this property called?(Field theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In what references the following property $P$ of  a  field $F$ is investigated?

**The property $P$:** For  all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ if $\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_{i}^{2}=0,\;\;f_{i}\in F$ then $f_{i}=0, \forall i\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a field is called [Formally Real.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formally_real_field)