# Prove $R = \{ a + bi : a,b \in \Bbb Z \}$ is a subring in $\Bbb C$ and $M = \{ a + bi : 3 \mid a \text{ and } 3\mid b\}$ is a maximal ideal in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Prove $R = \{ a + bi : a,b \in \Bbb Z  \}$ is a subring in $\Bbb C$ and that $M = \{ a + bi : 3 \mid a \text{ and } 3\mid b\}$ is a maximal ideal in $R$. I was able to prove that $R$ is a subring of $\Bbb C$ easily, since $\forall $ $x,y \in $ R,$x - y \in R$, and $xy \in R$. So indeed $R$ is a subring of $\Bbb C$. Now, it was also easy to show that $M$ is an ideal in $R$, since $M \subseteq R$ and, $\forall $ $c,d \in  M$, $c - d \in M$, and , $\forall r \in R$, $cr=rc \in  M$.

By a hint, I was guided to show that if $r + si \notin M$, then $3 \not\mid $ r or $3 \not\mid s $. Now, it is easy to show this implies that $3 \not\mid ( r^2 + s^2 )$. Then, I need to show that any ideal $I$ containing $r + si$ and $M$ must also contain $1$. I would be very grateful for any ideas. Much obliged

Comment: Let $\mathbb{Z}_{3}=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. One can prove that $\{a+bi \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{3}\}$ is  a field. The later is  a homomorphism image of R which kernel is your ideal..

Comment: a generalization: If M is  a  maximal Ideal in R such that R/M is  a  [formaly real field](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859489/what-is-this-property-calledfield-theory)(or at least a^2+b^2 never vanish) then $\{a+bi \mid a,b \in M\}$ is  a  maximal Ideal in the corresponding ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint, based on what you have already shown: if $I$ contains $M$ and $r+si$, then in particular $I$ contains $3$ and $r^{2}+s^{2}$. Since $3$ does not divide $r^{2}+s^{2}$ and $3$ is a prime number, it follows that $\gcd(r^{2}+s^{2}, 3) = 1$. Now use Bezout's lemma; feel free to comment if you need more assistance from here.

Comment: Okay, so I see that the gcd( r^2 + s^2 , 3) is 1. Then, this implies that I can express 1 as a linear combination, say 1 = u(3) + v(r^2 + s^2)

Comment: Yep, you got it! :)

Comment: So, does this mean 1 is in our ideal I? And that would imply that it was the whole Ring R

Comment: And another quick question, since I contains r + si, it is closed under multiplication, so you multiplied it by r - si to have it contain r^2 + s^2. From which set did the r-si come from? Thanks so much man

Comment: Yes, this shows $1$ is in our ideal $I$, since ideals are closed under addition and multiplication by elements of the ring $R$. This also answers your second question: $r-si$ is an element of $R$, and elements of $I$ are closed under multiplication by elements of $R$.