# Is the set of complex numbers a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Is the set of complex numbers of the form $\frac{x+y\sqrt{D}}{2}$ ring, where $D$ - fixed, square-free integer, $x,y$ - integers equal parity?

The answer is: This set is ring when $D \equiv 1 \ (mod4)$, but why?

Comment: Have you checked some examples, say $D=3$ or $D=-1$?

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692764/prove-r-a-bi-a-b-in-bbb-z-is-a-subring-in-bbb-c-and-m-a), for $D=-1$.

Comment: Because that's the integral closure of $\,\Bbb Z[\sqrt D],\,$ e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1058125/242).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's straightforward to check our set is closed under addition.

We need to make sure the set is closed under multiplication.

$$(\frac{x+y\sqrt{D}}{2})(\frac{a+b\sqrt{D}}{2})=$$

$$(\frac{xa+Dyb}{4}) + (\frac{xb+ya}{4})\sqrt{D}$$

Since x,y have the same parities and a,b have the same parities... xb and ya have the same parities. So $xb+ya$ is even.

So we know $\frac{xb+ya}{4} = \frac{n}{2}$ for some integer n

Now we need to make sure $xa+Dyb$ is similarly divisible by 2

We know $xa$ and $yb$ have the same parity using similar reasoning as before. So if D is odd this condition is satisfied. On the other hand if D is even, then if x,y,a,b are all odd, we break this condition. So D must be odd.

Finally we need to make sure that

$\frac{xa+Dyb}{2}$ and $\frac{xb+ya}{2}$ have the same parity

We just need to ensure the difference is divisible by 2:

$\frac{x(a-b)+y(Db-a)}{2}$

In other words we require.

$x(a-b)+y(Db-a) \equiv 0 (\mod 4)$

We already know D has to be odd... so D can only be 1 or 3 mod 4.

Assume $D\equiv 3 \mod 4$

We need to check $x(a-b)+y(3b-a) (\mod 4)$

substitute in a choice of $x=y=a=b=1$

this comes out to $2 \mod 4$. So $D \equiv 3\mod 4$ doesn't satisfy our condition.

On the other hand suppose $D \equiv 1 \mod 4$

$x(a-b)+y(1b-a) \equiv (x-y)(a-b) (\mod 4)$

Since (x-y) and (a-b) are both even, this comes out to $0 \mod 4$ for all valid choices of x,y,a,b

So we've proved that our set is closed under multiplication only for $D \equiv (1 \mod 4)$

So our set is a ring only for $D \equiv (1 \mod 4)$